# (Python graph-tool) Find paths of a specific length using graph-tool?

Tags: python, search, graph-theory, graph-tool

Is there a way to find paths between two vertices in a graph of a specific length?

I know I can find the shortest path using:

```
graph_tool.topology.all_shortest_paths
```

and that I can find paths of a maximum length using:

```
graph_tool.topology.all_paths
```

But is there a way to constrain these to find paths of a specific length, or at least paths between an upper and lower bound length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly implemented, but by using `all_paths()` you can simply ignore the paths that do not have the length you want.

Comment: Thanks, this will have to do then!